# Blur whole body except one div with js

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have div when i click this div, after i call js function and  want to blur whole page except one div.

**edit**

**added full code**

this is my full code (i use this template with backend **Django**)
but i think it is not problem with Django and it is my issue with front-end ->

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% include "./navbar.html" %}

<div class="relative pt-6  w-7/12 left-80 ">
    <div class="post">
        <div class="p-6 mb-12 pb-16 w-full h-auto break-all bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-200 shadow-md dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 border border-gray-400">
            <div class="mb-4">
                <form>
                    {% if fav %}
                        <button type="submit" name="fav" class="absolute right-2 top-5 text-5xl ">&#9733;</button>
                    {% else %}
                        <button type="submit" name="fav" class="absolute right-2 top-5 text-5xl ">&#9734;</button>
                    {% endif %}
                </form>
                <h1>{{ detail.user }}</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-2 flex ">
                {% for a in detail.category.all %}
                <p class="mr-2 text-sm text-blue-500">#{{ a.name }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <form class="float-right block" id="ld" action="{% url 'Profile:question-detail' pk=detail.id %}">
                <div class="vote circle">
                    {% if like_ex %}
                    <button type="submit" name="like" class="block mb-2 increment up border-4 border-blue-800"></button>
                    {% else %}
                    <button type="submit" name="like" class="block mb-2 increment up "></button>
                    {% endif %}

                    {% if dislike_ex %}
                    <button type="submit" name="dislike"
                            class="block mb-2 increment down border-4 border-blue-800"></button>
                    {% else %}
                    <button type="submit" name="dislike" class="block mb-2 increment down "></button>
                    {% endif %}

                    <div class="count" onclick="t()">{{ detail.point }}</div>
                </div>
                <button type="button"  onclick="show()" class="relative bottom-4  h-8 w-28 px-5  text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 focus:outline-none bg-white rounded-full border border-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-blue-700 focus:z-10 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:focus:ring-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-400 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700">აქტივობა</button>
            </form>
            <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">{{ detail.title }}</h5>
            <p class="mb-4 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">{{ detail.text }}</p>

                    <div class="activity ">
            <p class="hidden"  onclick="hide()" id="test">test</p>
        </div>
        </div>



        {% if can_update %}
            {% if owner %}
            <div class="relative bottom-8">
                <a href="{% url 'Profile:update-question' object.id %}">
                    <button class="relative inline-flex p-0.5 overflow-hidden text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 rounded-lg group bg-gradient-to-br from-purple-500 to-pink-500 group-hover:from-purple-500 group-hover:to-pink-500 hover:text-white dark:text-white focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-purple-200 dark:focus:ring-purple-800">
                            <span class="relative px-5 py-2.5 transition-all ease-in duration-75 bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 rounded-md group-hover:bg-opacity-0">
                                განახლება
                            </span>
                    </button>
                </a>
            </div>
            {% endif %}

        {% else %}
        <div class="relative bottom-8">
             <button class="relative inline-flex p-0.5 overflow-hidden text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 rounded-lg group bg-gradient-to-br from-purple-500 to-pink-500 group-hover:from-purple-500 group-hover:to-pink-500 hover:text-white dark:text-white focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-purple-200 dark:focus:ring-purple-800">
                    <span class="relative px-5 py-2.5 transition-all ease-in duration-75 bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 rounded-md group-hover:bg-opacity-0">
                        განახლების ლიმიტი ამოწურული გაქვს
                    </span>
             </button>
        </div>

        {% endif %}

    </div>


    <div class="w-full bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-200 shadow-md dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">

        <form class="bg-white rounded-lg px-4 pt-2" method="post" id="comment" novalidate>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
                {% for field in form %}
                {% if field.errors %}
                <div class="ml-3 my-2 bg-red-200 border border-red-200 text-red-700 px-2 py-2 rounded relative">
                    <ul class="">
                        {% for error in field.errors %}
                        <li>{{ error }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
                {% endif %}

                {% endfor %}
                <div class="w-full md:w-full px-3 mb-2 mt-2">
                    {% for field in form %}
                    {{field}}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>

                <div class="w-full md:w-full flex items-start md:w-full px-3">
                    <div class="-mr-1">
                        <a href="{ url Profile:question_detail detail.id }"><input type='submit' name="comment"
                                                                                   class="bg-white text-gray-700 font-medium py-1 px-4 border border-gray-400 rounded-lg tracking-wide mr-1 hover:bg-gray-100 cursor-pointer"
                                                                                   value='დაკომენტარება'></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="comments">
    {% for a in detail.question.all %}
    <div class="w-full bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-200 shadow-md dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 mt-8 mb-4 h-auto break-all p-4 border border-gray-400">
        <div>
            <p class="text-indigo-700 text-xl"> {{a.user}}</p>
        </div>
        <p class="fond-medium">{{a.text}}</p>
    </div>

    {% endfor %}
</div>

<script>
function show() {
   document.getElementById('test').style.display = "block";
   document.querySelectorAll('body >*:not(.test)')
  .forEach(node => node.style.filter = "blur(2px)")

<!--  console.log(document.querySelector('body >*:not(.test)'))-->
}


function hide() {
   document.getElementById('test').style.display = "none";

}
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

what should I do?
thank you all for helping

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('body >*:not(.test)').forEach(element => {
   element.style.filter = "blur(2px)";
});`

Comment: > The Document method `querySelector()` returns the **`first Element`** within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector.

Comment: @AlveMonke Nothing changed

Comment: Could you please edit your question to provide your entire `html` code? It's hard to figure out a solution without having it.

Comment: @AlveMonke yes just a moment

Comment: @AlveMonke can you see now?

Comment: Does changing `.test` to `#test` work?

Comment: I believe you're using the wrong target. Usually when you're targetting an ID you use #id, not .id (in your case would be `body >*:not(#test)`) but I believe your effect won't be achieved because test is not a direct child of your body html it would need to be for it to work.

Comment: @AlveMonke oh yes your are correct, it should be #test but nothing changed

Comment: @Hotwer i changed but it's same

Comment: when i run this code in console ```console.log(document.querySelector('body >*:not(#test)'))``` result is ```<meta charset="UTF-8" style="filter: blur(2px);">``` is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple Issues with your example.

First of all: you are using `document.getElementById('test')` while writing a query that contains `.test`.
You either have to use an Id or a Classname, if this mix is intended, please provide a minimal code example to replicate the issue.

Secondly: using `document.querySelector` you only receive one Node.
You might want to change it to

```js
document.querySelectorAll('body >*:not(.test)').forEach(e => e.style.filter = "blur(2px)");
```

to change all Nodes that were selected in said query.

Third:
If your test div is inside a Node that receives the blur, obviously it is blurred too. There is no circumvention other than only blurring only the siblings of said test element.

Comment: i try your code but nothig changed. i think correct answer is third. can i show you all html? i send with pastebin

Comment: sure. just put it into the question. preferrably using the paste function from stackoverflow.

Comment: yes but the number of lines is over 120 and would it be a good idea to insert it here?

Comment: Yes that's fine. It will make it scrollable. You could also reduce it to the minimum you see fit to reproduce the issue.

Comment: can you see now?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach has two issues:

1. You used `querySelector` - this only returns the first element that matches your selector. Change this to `querySelectorAll`, and you'll receive a [nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) containing all of the elements. You can then loop over these using `.forEach`, and apply the filter.
2. If you blur a parent element, all the children will also be blurred. Make sure the div you wish to exclude is a direct child of your body element.

The following should work:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('body >*:not(.test)')
  .forEach(node => node.style.filter = "blur(2px)")
```

Comment: i try this example but don't have any effect

Comment: I've implemented it in a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/6cfhqb7t/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the direct child node of your body tag, just like this:

```
<body>
<div class="booking-info">
    <div class="popup" id="pop">
        <img src="images/Tick.png" alt="">
        <h2>Congratulations!</h2>
        <p>Your reservations have been successfully booked. Thanks!</p>
        <button class="btn-style booking-btn" id="close-popup">Ok</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<script>
   document.querySelectorAll('body >*:not(.booking-info)').forEach(e => e.style.filter = "blur(3px)");
</script>
```

Here, at first I tried with the "popup" class which is not directly under the body tag and that's why the blurring effect was not working. But after trying with the direct child node class, blurring effect works except my desired block.